# pull data from linux server to windows spreadsheet

Tags: excel

I am working on a ms. excel presentation in windows7 environment and would like to pull some data from a csv file in linux server.  I manually copy the file line by line to the spreadsheet which is a bit troublesome and repetitive as the data get updated daily. Do you know how to automatically pull the data?

Comment: Just open the file in Excel. CSV is recognized by Excel and will open.

Answer (score 1):

How are you accessing the Linux server?

If you are using SSH/Putty/a terminal client interface, then see if you can use [FileZilla Client](https://filezilla-project.org/) (or similar) to connect with the SFTP protocol ( a part of SSH used for file transfer ), using your normal hostname/username/password details, and copy the file to your PC, then open it in Excel.

Otherwise, you can select all the lines at once, paste them into Excel, and use 'Text to Columns' on the 'Data' tab, while they are all selected, to process the comma separation into Excel cells.

Apart from that, see the Linux server administrators for a way to copy the file off - FTP, HTTP download, or have it emailed to you, or email it to yourself from the server. There's very likely some way to do it.